# ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD: Error: Can't create a new thread mysql running inside a docker

Tags: mysql, innodb, pool

upon increasing total number of pool connection from application to MySQL 40000 getting this error ER_CANT_CREATE_THREAD.

MySQL conf file looks like this

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size=100G  # from 128M to use half of your RAM for data/index storage
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=32  # from 1 to reduce mutex contention
innodb_lru_scan_depth=1024  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
max_connections=65536
max_prepared_stmt_count=204800
max_connect_errors=100000
thread_cache_size=8192
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
query_cache_size = 0
innodb_read_io_threads = 64
innodb_write_io_threads = 64
innodb_thread_concurrency = 0
innodb_io_capacity = 2000
sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

Comment: How much RAM are you allowing Docker to have?  Many of those settings are very high.

Comment: I have not set up any RAM allocation on docker. only set up on the mysqld conf file....

Comment: Do you have at least 128GB on the machine?

Comment: yes machine is 128gb RAM

Comment: `max_connections=65536` is unreasonably, perhaps dangerously, high.  Lower it to 5000.

Comment: if we require to achieve that many connections for the operations running what is the solution?

Comment: we are building the solution for IoT which generates 90000 requests for every minute how do we solve his kind of scenarios using mysql

Comment: Without a thread pool, 1 connection = 1 thread = 1 pthread, and this will break down. This is what the thread pool is for, multiplex many connections = user sessions with only a few worker threads = pthread, so that MySQL can scale better.

Answer (score 1):

`max_connections=65536` is unreasonably, perhaps dangerously, high.  Lower it to 100.

If 90000 connections are *active* at once, MySQL will meltdown.  It is better to avoid too many connections than to let them stumble over each other.  (Consider what would happen if you let 10000 people into a grocery store *at the same time*.  Traffic would be so clogged up that people might take an hour to buy just one item.)

If your IoT action is a quick connect-insert-disconnect, that should take very few milliseconds.

If the connections came in *very* smoothly and take 10ms *elapsed* each, they could handle 90K per minute with only `max_connections=15`.

Benchmarks have shown that MySQL gets bottlenecked at not much more than the number of CPU cores that you have.

So, by limiting the number of *current active* connections to `max_connections=100` should be a safe compromise.

Set `back_log` to a higher number, maybe 1000.  (I do not have a feel for what a good number is.)  The idea is that *delaying* the connection is better than letting it in, only to be stalled.

I am confident that MySQL can handle 90K IoT inserts per minute, but only if you take the advice here.

You mentioned "connection pooling".  The 100 and 1000 should be moved back into the pooling layer.  Or get rid of the layer.  (It is hard to say which would be better.)

Comment: there is a read and update in the 90000 requests along with insert command as well

Comment: @santhosh - If MySQL can handle each request in 10ms, and if 90 can be progressing simultaneously, then all 90K might finish in 10 seconds.  Its more about "transactions per second" than about "simultaneous".

Answer (score 0):

Please lower [innodb_read_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_read_io_threads) and [innodb_write_io_threads](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_write_io_threads) to 4. Those variables should be increased for docker environments.

If you want more than 4 threads each, make sure there is enough RAM allocated.